# How to create Feature Class based on DBF schema?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, attribute-table, excel, schema-architecture

I have an attribute table schema (about 30 fields) stored in an Excel document, which I exported as a dbf. I can easily make a geodatabase table from this, using the Excel sheet as a template. How can I create a feature class from this schema (either from the Excel sheet or the dbf or the geodatabase table)? The Excel sheet is blank except for the field names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding two extra fields for X and Y (perhaps Longitude and Latitude), then I think you should be able to use Display XY Data from the layer context menu, followed by Data|Export Data to create the feature class.

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't want to display the fields available in the dropdowns for X and Y. I even put a few coordinate values in the columns, but that didn't help. I can still display XY data from other Excel sheets as normal, but this sheet does not want to be displayed.

Comment: Presumably, your Excel spreadsheet will be small, so if you want to email me a copy of it (graeme@polygeo.com.au) with the name of the coordinate system you are wanting for the feature class, then I can give it a quick test and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your help, created the feature class as you mentioned and then just deleted the temporary fields.